# How to access my IIS server? (Find my ISS IP address)

Tags: iis

I just purchased some hardware that requires me to install and run IIS (SQL Express). I did that, and everything went just fine. However, I need to connect the hardware to my computer via WiFi by using the IP address of the computer where ISS is installed on.

I have tried using the IP shown in ipcongig, but it will not connect.

Basically, how to access the server via (a public) IP address.

Also, do I need to keep the computer on all the time in order for it to be accessed from outside?

Comment: If your computer is off, it can't run code.

Comment: We need some clarification. First... 1. Are you trying to conect to SQL Express or IIS? Assuming IIS; 2. Are you tying to access IIS from your local LAN or from the Internet? 3. Can you connect to the web site (IIS) from the machine that IIS is installed on? 4. What error message or response do you get in your web browser when you try to connect and fail?

Answer (score 0):

1.make sure your ip address is static , in order to connect to your computer from outside
 and check your iis started or not

2.Yes , you need keep computer on to be accessed